# Double click issue in windows 8 IE browsers

Tags: jquery

Windows 8 IE browsers i am unable to prevent the double click.

```
$('#id').click(function (el)
            { 
                    if (!el.detail || el.detail == 1)
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                                        ...........
                                     });
                    }
            });
```

this above code working fine in Windows XP and windows 7 for prevent double click. But in windows 8 "el.detail" was not supported. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: do you want to prevent dbclick or want to prevent sending second ajax request while first one has not completed

Comment: i want to prevent sending second ajax request while first one has not completed

Comment: That is not the same as double click, you need to wait till the ajax request is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, what you need to do is to prevent the ajax request being sent while another one is in progress

```
$('#id').click(function (el){ 
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('inProgress')){
        $this.data('inProgress', true)
        $.ajax({
        }).always(function(){
            $this.data('inProgress', false)
        });
    }
});
```